# String pattern that prevents the first character being a whitespace

Tags: java, regex, string, whitespace

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out a pattern that will allow anything to be entered, as long as the first character isn't a whitespace. 
I've tried

```
String pattern = "[^\\s][a-zA-Z0-9\\W ]+";"
```

and `"([a-zA-Z0-9\\W]+)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\W]+\\s[a-zA-Z0-9\\W]+)+)"` as well as several other variants, with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Java btw

Comment: Have you tried `string.charAt(0)==' '`?. Why use a *regex*?

Comment: Try: `String pattern = "^\\S.*$"`

Comment: OP Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work

```
^[^\s].*
```

The first caret denotes start of line, and the second negation.

Answer (score 2):

Most regular expression matching defaults to searching anywhere in the string for the pattern.  Since you are concerned specifically with the beginning of the string, you should prefix the entire regex with '^' to anchor the match to the beginning of the input.

```
String pattern = "^[^\\s][a-zA-Z0-9\\W ]+";
```

It can be a bit confusing since `^` has a very different meaning when it appears inside square brackets.  Inside the brackets, as you know, it signals matching the complement of (ie all characters except) the set of characters listed in the brackets.  Outside, it is simply an anchor for the beginning of the string.

In this non-bracketed use, it is the opposite of `$` which anchors a match at the *end* of a string, eg `/end$/` will match "friend" but not "ending" - you can read more about anchors at this URL: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: Thanks very much, this works perfectly. By any chance would you be able to give me a brief explanation on how it actually works? I've only been studying Java for a few months, so to me this reads "Not not space (so space) followed by pretty much anything". Again, the help would mean a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about the rest, you can just use [`String.charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) with [`Character.isSpaceChar(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char)), **or** [`String.codePointAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) with [`Character.isSpaceChar(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(int)).

The second method is the correct way to deal with Unicode string and code point in astral plane, while the first method is broken, but usable when your input only has character from the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).

Code for the second method:

```
boolean startWithSpace = Character.isSpaceChar(input.codePointAt(0));
```

`Character.isSpaceChar` checks for any whitespace character **according to Unicode**. Not to be confused with `Character.isWhitespace`, which checks for whitespace character **according to Java**.